# element(by.binding('...'),getText() gets a whole block of text instead of only the element

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am testing the result of `{{price}}`and `{{getAdditionalKm}}` of my AngularJS Application with Protractor. Here is part of the html I want to test:

```html
<h1>{{ price(distance, time, time_standing, airport) | currency }}</h1>

<p>Preis im Detail:<p>
    ...
    <b>Distanz</b><br>
    {{ getFreeKm( time) }} Freikilometer<br>
    {{ getAdditionalKm(distance, time) }} km a {{ fee_additionalkm | currency }} Zusätzlicher Kilometer Preis = {{ getFee_additionalKm(distance, time) | currency }} Kilometer Preis<br>
    ...
```

In my protractor Scenario I run `expect(element(by.binding('price')).getText()).toEqual('20,30 €');` which works as expected and only gets the price ('20.30 €').

However running `expect(element(by.binding('getAdditionalKm')).getText()).toEqual('50');`gets me everything after the `{{ price }}` element. This is the output if I run the Protractor Test:

```
...
Failures:

  1) c2g test get price with 50 additional kms
   Message:
     Expected 'Zeit
0 Tage a 59,00 ? = 0,00 ?
0 Stunden a 14,90 ? = 0,00 ?
20 Minuten a 0,29 ? = 5,80 ?
Distanz
50 Freikilometer
50 km a 0,29 ? Zusätzlicher Kilometer Preis = 14,50 ? Kilometer Preis
Sonstiges
0,00 ? Zeit stehend
0,00 ? Flughafenpauschale' to equal '50'.
...
```

Why is protractor not selecting only the `{{getAdditionalKm}}` element? Do I need to change the html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getAdditionalKm` is not within its own element, so the entire element that contains it gets selected. Instead of using the `.toEqual` comparison to `.toContain`. If possible you could also put the `getAdditionalKm` binding in its own element.

Comment: Good point, though `toContain` would not be reliable in this case.

Comment: Obviously to put `getAdditionalKm` is the better solution. A div works, but breaks the layout. Do you know any html element that doesn't harm the layout?

Comment: @mles you could try a `span` or just any element and use CSS to prevent it from affecting the layout.